# $\mathbb{F}_2[X,Y]/(Y^2 + Y + 1,X^2 + X + Y )$ and $\bigg(\mathbb{F}_2[Y]/(Y^2 + Y + 1)\bigg)[X]/(X^2 + X + \bar{Y})$ are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to construct an isomorphism between $\mathbb{F}_2[X,Y]/(Y^2 + Y + 1,X^2 + X + Y )$ and $\bigg(\mathbb{F}_2[Y]/(Y^2 + Y + 1)\bigg)[X]/(X^2 + X + \bar{Y})$. I tried to put the following application:

\begin{align*}
  \varphi:\mathbb{F}_2[X,Y]/(Y^2 + Y + 1,X^2 + X + Y )&\longrightarrow& \bigg(\mathbb{F}_2[Y]/(Y^2 + Y + 1)\bigg)[X]/(X^2 + X + \bar{Y})& \\
  P(X,Y)+(Y^2 + Y + 1,X^2 + X + Y )&\longmapsto&  P(X,\bar{Y})+(X^2 + X + \bar{Y})
\end{align*}
It is obvious that $ \varphi$ is a surjective morphism, but I have a problem showing that $ \varphi$ is injective. Does this morphism solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi : \mathbb F_2 [X,Y] \to \bigg(\mathbb{F}_2[Y]/(Y^2 + Y + 1)\bigg)[X]/(X^2 + X + \bar{Y})$ be the morphism of rings which send $X$ to $\bar X$ and $Y$ to $\bar Y$. It is surjective and, since $\phi( Y^2 + Y + 1) = \phi(X^2 + X + Y) = 0$, it induces a surjective ring morphism :
$\bar \phi: \mathbb{F}_2[X,Y]/(Y^2 + Y + 1,X^2 + X + Y ) \to \bigg(\mathbb{F}_2[Y]/(Y^2 + Y + 1)\bigg)[X]/(X^2 + X + \bar{Y})$

Assume that $\bar{\phi}(P)= 0$. Then $P(\bar X,\bar Y) = 0$. Therefore :
$$P(X,\bar Y) \in {}(X^2 + X + \bar Y)$$
and :
$$P(X,Y) \in (X^2 + X + Y , Y^2 + Y + 1)$$
so $P = 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[X,Y]/(Y^2 + Y + 1,X^2 + X + Y )$.

So $\bar \phi$ is an isomorphism.